# How to modify my url for php website in IIS?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, iis-8.5

I have a website hosted in IIS 8.5. The website is accessible by domain name publicly. I have added "HTTP Redirect" to redirect `example.com` to `example.com/project_name/folder`. And in IIS "Default document" I have included `index.php`.

When I enter domain_name.com in browser, it shows `example.com/project_name/folder/login`.
But I don't want this full path to show in URL. I want it to appear as `example.com/login`

Can somebody share the detailed steps including regular expressions, that I need to do configure in URL rewrite to achieve this?

Here is my attempt :
I have added a Url rewrite rule with the following config :

Name : URL_Shortening ;
Match URL :
Requested URL : Matches the pattern ;  Using : Regular Expressions ;
Pattern : ^dual-rebama.ndtv.com/[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+/[a-z]+/([a-z]+)   ; Ignore case : true ;
Action type : Rewrite ;
Rewrite URL : dual-rebama.ndtv.com/{R:1}     ;
Append query string : true  ;
Stop processing of subsequent rules : false

But this rewrite rule is not working. Please suggest where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What have you researched? What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? We are not a free do-my-research or write-my-code or request-a-tutorial service. We'll _help_ you with a _specific_ issue with _your_ attempt to implement what you need and solve your problem. Please take the [tour], and read [ask] and how to create a [mre] and then update your question. Thanks.

Comment: HTTP redirects change the URL.   I'm not super familiar with IIS, but can  you change that from a redirect to a rewrite?

Comment: I have added a Url rewrite rule with the following config :      Name : URL_Shortening ; Match URL : Requested URL : Matches the pattern ; Using : Regular Expressions ; Pattern : ^dual-rebama.ndtv.com/[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+/[a-z]+/([a-z]+)   ; Ignore case : true ; Action type : Rewrite ; Rewrite URL : dual-rebama.ndtv.com/{R:1}     ; Append query string : true  ;  Stop processing of subsequent rules : false         But this rewrite rule is not working. Please suggest where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect example.com/project_name/folder/login to example.com/login, you can try this rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
     <rule name="Remove testapp" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="^project_name/folder/(.*)$" />
       <action type="Rewrite" url=http://dual-rebama.ndtv.com/{R:1} appendQueryString="false" />
     </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```